# How to pass values through a WCF Service in a ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, wcf, outlook-addin

I am working on a Outlook Addin for our Website. I want to pass the selected date, time and subject from outlook calender to our website which loads in a webcontrol inside Outlook. The Webservice is WCF.

I can transfer the calender values to WCF like this:

```
 [OperationContract]
string getBookingURL(string guid, BookingRequest request,string token,string exitURL);
```

BookingRequest is the class where i pass the calender values:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class BookingRequest
{
    public long bookingID { get; set; }
    public DateTime startUTC { get; set; }
    public DateTime endUTC { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public int numParticipants { get; set; }
}
```

now the next step would be something like this on my asp.net Website:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

if (BookingRequest!=Null) then
FromDateTextfield.Text = BookingRequest.startUTC
ToDateTextfileld.Text = BookingRequest.EndUTC
SubjectTextfield.Text = BookingRequest.subject
End If

End Sub
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the Values from WCF to the Webpage on load.

Maybe there is a solution without WCF.
Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that you have created proxy class on client side. so using the object you can call service using proxy object. as bellow:

```
 ProxyServClient client = new ProxyServClient();
 BookingRequest bookingrequest = client.GetBookingDetails();
 if(BookingRequest!=Null)
  {
    FromDateTextfield.Text = BookingRequest.startUTC;
    ToDateTextfileld.Text = BookingRequest.EndUTC;
    SubjectTextfield.Text = BookingRequest.subject;
  }
```

for this you have to create Booking request property class which has properties as your service is going to return.